# How can I link to a specific element of an external website WITHOUT using id? (i.e. NOT using "#some-id" at the end of my anchor tag's href url)?

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom, browser

I understand you can link to specific id attributes by doing the following:

`<a href="http://www.external-website.com/page#some-id">Link</a>`

But what if there are no ids in the external html doc to target?

Seems strange that there wouldn't be a way to link directly to an element using selectors such as class or another attribute.

Please let me know if you know a way to implement this.

Thank you!

Comment: For both internal (in-page) or external links, the functionality is the same. Under HTML4, there were two options: using the `id` attribute on any tag, or using anchors with the `name` attribute. Under HTML5, the `name` attribute is obsolete. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#scroll-to-fragid (look at the end of that section).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the JS function `scrollIntoView()`: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

In their example, they show the following:

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

Basically, you can select an element however you'd like (such as using [`querySelector()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)), and then call `scrollIntoView()` on it. If you've never used it before, `querySelector()` lets you select elements using CSS-style selectors, which means you're not limited to IDs.

The other other part of your question requires adding something to the original URL to indicate which element to scroll to. Here's an idea of what a complete solution might look like. Let's say you're using a URL like this, and you want to scroll to the first element with a particular class: https://example.com/mypage?scrollToClass=foo

```
// parse the query params and store the one for the class you want to scroll to
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const scrollToClass = urlParams.get('scrollToClass');

// select the first element with that class, and scroll to it
const elementToScrollTo = document.querySelector("." + scrollToClass);
elementToScrollTo.scrollIntoView();
```

I haven't tested this, but hopefully this gives a good idea of an approach.